# How do you remove JPA connections in JBoss Tools Project Properties?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I am using JBoss Tools for Eclipse Kepler Release.

In any project in Project Properties there is a JPA tree with an Add Connections link and a Connect... link.  I have created several connections during development of several projects.  But, some of them are really quite useless now.  How can I delete some of these?  I[image: JBoss Project Properties JPA Tab]

[image: JBoss Project Properties JPA Tab Connections Selected]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Press Ctrl+3
2. Start typing 'Data Source Explorer'
3. Select "Views 'Data Source Explorer'"

Comment: There it is, the Data Source Explorer.  Now the pesky extra non-needed Data sources are gone.